# If $[u,v] = 0$, are $u$ and $v$ both curl-free?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, curl

Suppose $u$ and $v$ are two vector fields in the plane, with $u$ and $v$ linearly independent and Lie bracket $[u,v]$ zero everywhere. Does it follow that $u$ and $v$ are both curl-free? Intuitively, I would think that commutativity of the flows of $u$ and $v$ is stronger than integrability of each individual field, but is there an algebraic way to recover $\nabla \times u=0$ from $[u,v]=0$?

If this fact is true, the linear independence of $u$ and $v$ must play some essential role, since of course $[u,u]=0$ for any $u$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We shouldn't expect this to be true. Consider any noncurlfree, nonvanishing vector field $U$. In (local) flowbox coordinates $(s, t)$ we have $U = \partial_s$, and $[\partial_s, \partial_t] = 0$, so not only is the local version of the statement false, the condition $[U, V] = 0$ doesn't impose any local restriction on $U$ near any point where $U$ is nonzero.

**Example** The pair $$U := \exp x \,\partial_y, \qquad V := \partial_x + y \partial_y$$ is (pointwise) linearly independent and satisfies $[U, V] = 0$ but $\nabla \times U = \exp x$. (In this example, we actually have $\nabla \times V = 0$, but this is not necessary either, as we can replace $V$ with $\tilde V = x V$, which satisfies the same conditions but $\nabla \times \tilde V = y$.)

Comment: I see. I expected $V$ to integrate to the $t$ coordinate function, but the flaw in my reasoning is that if $V\cdot U\neq 0$ the path integral along the flow of $U$ is not zero. Are $U,V$ curl-free if they are everywhere orthogonal?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean: In the first paragraph we're taking our second field (in $(s, t)$ coordinates) to be $\partial_t$, whose flow is translation (in those coordinates). By your question, do you mean: If $[U, V] = 0$ and $U \cdot V = 0$, then is it necessarily true that $\nabla \times U = \nabla \times V = 0$? If so, I'd suggest asking that as a separate question.

Comment: Yes, that's my (follow-up) question (or at least, my attempt to salvage the original claim). I mean, I can ask a separate question, but I'm hesitant to flood the site with minor variations of the same question as I flail about to find the right salvage...

Comment: That's actually the recommended behavior (no doubt there's plenty of discussion about it in meta). I might avoid asking more than two or three questions with small variations in a short time, but AFAIK we're not at that point yet. At any rate, a simple local counterexample is $U = x \partial_x + y \partial_y$ and $V = -y \partial_x + x \partial_y$ (NB: $V$ is just the vector field produced by rotating the vectors of $U$ at each point anticlockwise by $\frac{\pi}{2}$), but of course $U, V$ are not pointwise linearly independent at $0$.